# electron has blue outline/frame when launch

Tags: electron, frame, outline

I want to use the same window outline like vscode:
[image]

but here is my window at launch

[image]

my window config

```js
new BrowserWindow({
    minHeight: 400,
    minWidth: 600,
    center: true,
    frame: false,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",

    webPreferences: {
        spellcheck: false,
        webSecurity: true,
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false,
        enableWebSQL: false,
        images: false,
        webgl: false,
    },
});
```

deps:

```json
"electron": "17.0.0",
"electron-builder": "^22.14.13"
```

Comment: Is possible to change outline ?

Comment: Have you tried `thickFrame: false`?

Comment: `frame: false` should work. Can you add to your question the version of Electron you are using and expand on the provided code? IE: `const win = new BrowserWindow( … );`. It would be interesting to see your entire window config file. Regarding your problem, the approach would be to hide the frame, add a header to drag your application around with (if needed) and using CSS, add a thin corner curved border to the `<body>` tag (or something similar).

Comment: @mxmissile didn't work to me, I found a api: `win.getNativeWindowHandle()` , it look like the way i need, but i don't know how to use it 

Comment: @mxmissile oh i found this issue : https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/33152#issuecomment-1059700797 ， it work, has a vscode launch outline, but it do not show any view when i use `loadFile` or `loadURL` 

Answer (score 0):

OMG, I did it!!!!

```js
// @ts-check
const { BrowserWindow, app } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const { Library } = require("ffi-napi");

app.disableHardwareAcceleration();

function createWindow() {
    return new BrowserWindow({
        minHeight: 400,
        minWidth: 600,
        center: true,
        frame: false,
        show: true,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",

        webPreferences: {
            spellcheck: false,
            webSecurity: true,
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
        },
    });
}

async function openWindow() {
    const win = createWindow();

    // ffi - napi;
    var ffi = Library("user32.dll", {
        SetWindowLongA: ["int", ["int", "int", "long"]],
        SetWindowPos: ["int", ["int", "int", "int", "int", "int", "int", "int"]],
    });
    // THICK frame
    const WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000;
    // show window
    const SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
    // draw a thick frame
    ffi.SetWindowLongA(win.getNativeWindowHandle().readUint32LE(), -16, WS_THICKFRAME);
    // show window
    ffi.SetWindowPos(win.getNativeWindowHandle().readUint32LE(), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    win.center();

    if (app.isPackaged) {
        await win.loadFile("public/index.html");
    } else {
        await win.loadURL("http://localhost:3000");
    }

    return win;
}

exports.createWindow = createWindow;
exports.openWindow = openWindow;
```